# Can I use the fitness function in Xgboost

Tags: r, xgboost

I have a situation in which I do not have class labels, but I can express my task through a fitness function and I would like to use Xgboost to solve.

```
# some data without labels
dat <- matrix(rnorm(10000),ncol = 5)
library(xgboost)
dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data=dat,label=....? )
dtest <- xgb.DMatrix(data=dat,label=....?)
```

In order not to litter the example, I will not write the fitness function completely, I will just make a layout.

```
fitness <- function(preds){
  #....takes a vector returns a single number
  return(  max(preds)  )
}
```

The question is: can I embed my fitness function in `myobjectiveXGB` func?

```
myobjectiveXGB <- function(preds, dtrain) {
   labels <- getinfo(dtrain, "label")
  
   fit =  fitness(pred)   ### my fintess fun
  grad = ....?
  hess = ....?

  return(list(grad = grad, hess = hess))
}
```

Comment: Is it possible you need an optimization algorithm instead?  xgboost is for regression and classification.  If this is the case, `optim` from base R would be a good place to start.

Comment: the fact is that optimization algorithms do not predict new data